# Workstation vs Server for a 15 user office setting?

Tags: file-server, print-server

I have a task to install a file/print server for our office. We're 12 users that could expand in the near future for up to 15-18 users. I'm aware that server class hardware is of higher quality/reliability than consumer machines. However, in my country new servers are extremely expensive. For example, a Dell T110 ii would nearly cost double the labeled price on a Dell web store. Moreover, importing a server would cause much additional cost of customs + shipment. This is why I'm thinking of locally buying a used workstation like a Dell precision or HP XW machine.

Would a workstation give me the necessary reliability to file serve the office? given that downtime is very counter productive and might cost money; and
data loss would be very costly. So, would a workstation with a RAID controller ensures the same redundancy a good server should provide? I'm planning to have regular backups to the cloud + may be turn an old machine into a local backup machine.

I'm planning to run a windows server 2008 or a SBS 2008.

Comment: Server OS on workstation hardware is fine for testing purposes, but installing a Server OS on workstation hardware isn't really the norm, and is probably off topic here, as it's not something that is a recommended or supported configuration for professional production systems. Even overlooking this, the answer to your question largely depends upon the specifications of the workstation and how it is going to be used. We can't really judge that for you, so any answers posted here are going to be purely opinion based, again off topic here.

Comment: This makes sense. 
And apologies for that the question happened to be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

A **GOOD** Server will have things like redundant Network Cards and power supplies if you are looking for HA.

If you are buying second hand, you might consider just going for someone's throw away server. A used server is probably about as reliable as a new workstation. If cost for hardware is truly an obstacle and up time is a must... your best bet might be to host the server in the cloud. Pay amazon a monthly fee to worry about up time.... assuming you have the internet connection for it.